Plaid webhook 'heal'
I'm currently trying to make sure my app that uses Plaid, can recover from hooks not received within last 24 hours.
When a new event happens, Plaid sends a webhook and if its not successful it retries up to 24 hours.
But what if that window is missed?
I see  the docs state:

If you (or Plaid) experience downtime for longer than Plaid's retry
period, you will lose webhooks. If you use webhooks for state
transitions, ensure your application can self-heal by requesting Item
state from Plaid's other endpoints if a webhook is not received within
a window. All data present in webhooks is also present in our other
APIs.

But what does it mean with self-heal?
Can I start requesting webhooks somehow?
Does the /item/get make the webhooks start working again?

That documentation is poorly worded, but essentially means implementing an alternative flow if webhooks are not working. The exact details of this will depend on the business logic of your app.
For example: let's say you're using Auth, and you rely on the SMS_MICRODEPOSITS_VERIFICATION webhook to know that the end user has verified their account via micro-deposits. The text here is suggesting that you have some kind of polling or recovery mechanism where if you know your webhook receiver was down, or if the webhook was expected but not received, you call /accounts/get to check the verification_status field, which contains the same information that the webhook would have given.
As an aside, you actually can get the value of the most recent webhook sent about an Item via the last_webhook field returned by /item/get, but because this only stores the last webhook and only provides the code and timestamp rather than the full body of the webhook, it might not be sufficient for all use cases.

Hi Alex, again you are extremely helpful.
Is there way to tell Plaid to heal that webhook and start trying to send events again?
I find that if I missed the 24h webhook window, the item will never send another webhook for another event. So basically that item is doomed to never have a webhook update

I think that might be a misunderstanding of the docs -- if a given webhook can't be delivered, Plaid will give up on retrying it after 24 hours, but that doesn't impact other webhooks / events, just the specific one that was missed. If a new action happens on that Item to trigger a new webhook, Plaid will send that new webhook as normal.

I did more testing.
I have not received a single webhook for multiple accounts since 3 days ago.
The bank accounts in question did have transactions every single day.
I was expecting PLAID to send webhooks at least once a day every time there is a new transaction to report.
Am I missing something or not understanding the way the webhooks work?

@AAlferez you can call /item/get and check the status.last_webhook field to see if Plaid tried to send any webhooks. Also try calling /transactions/sync or /transactions/get to make sure there are transactions updates; a connection issue w/the bank could prevent Plaid from seeing updates. Also, you'll only get transactions webhooks if you put transactions in the products array when you called /link/token/create; you won't get webhooks if you aren't subscribed to the Transactions product. If none of this helps, try filing a support ticket via the Dashboard.
